# Google analytics API - check if demographics are enabled

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I would like to use google analytics API, to query for unique users grouped by gender or age category.(metric ga:users, and dimension ga:userAgeBracket or ga:userGender)

For this to work you have to enable 2 things in my GA account:

1. Advertising Reporting Features
2. Enable Demographics and Interests reports.

Regarding those 2 configs I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to check if those 2 options are enabled, using google api?
2. If those 2 options are **not** enabled, can I enable them through google api?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Catalin, were you able to find a way to check the status of Demographics and Interest report via API?

Comment: Hi, I've stop investigating this issue, for the moment we are telling to our clients to manually check their account and enable the option of needed.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the reply.